# to update the data I need to reload the page, how can I avoid this?

Tags: react-redux, local-storage

I have an application that saves the user in localStorage, I have checks for the existence of  user on localStorage

```
componentDidMount(): void {
    const {getNotes,} = this.props;
    const userDataJSON = localStorage.getItem('userData'); 

    if (userDataJSON) {
      const {userID, sessionID,} = JSON.parse(userDataJSON);
      return getNotes({sessionID, userID,});
    }
}
```

but i have same checks in other blocks of code and i decide do it in utils

```
const userDataJSON = localStorage.getItem('userData');

export const userID = userDataJSON ? JSON.parse(userDataJSON).userID : null;
export const sessionID = userDataJSON ? JSON.parse(userDataJSON).sessionID : null;
export const username = userDataJSON ? JSON.parse(userDataJSON).username : '';
```

but data doesn't refresh when i logout and login in same session, i need reload page to correct work, how to refresh variables without reload page?
when i don't use utils all work good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that the code you are exporting on utils is only executed once (on initial load), because you are only storing the value in that moment, you could change those to be functions like this:

```
export const getUserData = () => {
  const data = localStorage.getItem('userData');
  return JSON.parse(data);
};
```

And you then when you use it, it will get the current value each time

```
const {userID, sessionID, username} = getUserData();
```

Another approach to avoid checking local storage each time you need the value could be to update the value on your state when modified and bring from local storage on initial mount, like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = getUserData();
}
updateUsername(username) {
  this.setState({ username });
  setUserData({ username }); // Assuming this one
}
```

Comment: ty, i resolve this problem like you, but i return { userID, sessionID, username }